# Answering Machine on Android

Tags: audio, calls

Playing audio to telephony uplink is possible, but the microphone input data is also transmitted.

1. How to switch off microphone on Android devices?
2. Is there a possibility to play audio to telephony uplink while call on mute?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I play an audio recording over an open phone conversation?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9992/how-can-i-play-an-audio-recording-over-an-open-phone-conversation)

Comment: @GATHrawn,

NO,the suggested solution is related to recording which in fact quite opposite to Answering machine feature.

Comment: The question is about playing back a piece of pre-recorded audio over the phone conversation, which is exactly point 2 of your question. Currently the only answer (which hasn't been accepted) is giving a workaround of playing pre-recorded audio whilst letting the inbuilt microphone pick it up during a call. It's not a good solution, but it is a solution. Things may have changed since that answer was posted June, if so anyone is welcome to post another answer which the OP could accept. Disregarding any answers that question is still very, very similar to this one.

Comment: well more precise, point 2: is all about playing an audio to uplink while MIC on Mute.. Recording is w.r.t to Downlink/MIC which is not the case here. please note that Playing and recording are two different issues here while point 2 just playing.And Recording(MIC/Downlik only) which is indeed achievable via android API on some hardware.

Comment: The other question isn't about recording, it's about playing "a recording", i.e., an audio file.  You're right that the other question doesn't mention anything about muting the mic, though, so I think they are fine to stay separate.  I'd encourage you to answer the other question, since it sounds like you've discovered how to play audio over the call without using the mic.

Comment: Thx Mr.Read, I have updated the other question with answer hope thats help. although its 8 months old post hope someone finds useful.

Comment: if you mean via code, you can mute the microphone with AudioManager setMicrophoneMute(boolean on) but this is not a development site and I don't know if you can still stream (like you posted in the linked question) when the mic is muted or not. if you do mean via code, then this question should be moved to stack overflow.

Comment: Not via code. any 3rd party app or any settings on device,

Answer (score 4):

I have been developing my own answer machine application and hit two major stumbling blocks. One is that `setMicrophoneMute(boolean on)` simply doesn't work. And the other issue is playing an audio greeting down the phone line.

This isn't possible due to hardware restrictions and it doesn't even work if the microphone is switched on and the audio is played through the speakers.

Comment: Have you found the solution ?

Comment: @mark Have you found the solution?

Comment: @Jack - it's possible, but both cases require rooted ROMs to work, thus one of them (ALSA-based) depends on Qualcomm chipsets.

Comment: @Hunt, wondering what you have found in that time

Comment: Are there any news?